# ObjectListView Flickers/Flashes when adding a new list object

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, objectlistview

When I update my `objectListView` list it flickers/flashes white, is this normal behaviour or can it be prevented. The list gets updated around every 1-5 seconds using the `AddObject` method if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it by using the `FastObjectListView` class instead...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to alleviate some of the flickering by Freezing and Thawing the ObjectListView widget as well.

---

Mike Driscoll

Blog:   http://blog.pythonlibrary.org

Comment: Unfortunately Freezing and Thawing the widget doesnt make any difference